# URLS.PY and VIEWS.PY slug removal

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I tried to word this specifically but the dilemma is as follows:
The image will not load as the slug is being added on the detail page, but loads fine in the index.html.[image]

`post.image` is the code you should be looking for... works in index.html but not post_detail... Something is off in the views/urls.. tried many combos but still getting my brain wrapped around the intricacies of url patterns. I need the image in the detail to point to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/placeholder_cake.PNG` and not `'http://127.0.0.1:8000/carrot-cake/static/placeholder_cake.PNG` (basically without the slug)..

Thanks to anyone that assists!

index.html

```
            <div class="col-md-8 mt-3 left">
                {% for post in post_list %}
                    <div class="card mb-4">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ post.image }}" alt="Card image cap">
                        <h2 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
                        <p class="card-text text-muted h6">{{ post.author }} | {{ post.created_on}} </p>
                        <p class="card-text">{{post.content|slice:":200" }}</p>
                        <a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.slug %}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More &rarr;</a>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
```

post_detail.html

```
            {% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}
            <!-- {% load static %} -->

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 card mb-4  mt-3 left  top">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h1>{% block title %} {{ objest.title }} {% endblock title %}</h1>
                    <p class=" text-muted">{{ post.author }} | {{ post.created_on }}</p>

                    <!-- /carrot-cake/static/placeholder_cake -->

                    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ post.image }}" alt="Card image cap">
                    <p class="card-text "><pre class="recipe">{{ object.content | safe }}</pre></p>
                </div>
                </div>

                {% block sidebar %} {% include 'sidebar.html' %} {% endblock sidebar %}
                </div>
            </div>

            {% endblock content %}
```

models.py

```
            class Post(models.Model):
                title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
                slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
                author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
                updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
                content = models.TextField()
                created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
                status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
                image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static', null=True, blank=True)   #creates folder called amiibo under the main media folder and uploads there

                class Meta:
                    ordering = ['-created_on']

                def __str__(self):
                    return self.title
```

views.py

```
                class PostList(generic.ListView):
                    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
                    template_name = 'index.html'

                class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
                    model = Post
                    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
```

urls.py

```
                urlpatterns = [
                    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
                    path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
                ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The context objects you're referring to in the detail template are a bit mixed up.

You're using the generic `DetailView`, which by default adds the specific object to the context as `object`. But you're trying to refer to it as both object and post. So try to keep it to `object`;

```
            {% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}
            <!-- {% load static %} -->

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 card mb-4  mt-3 left  top">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h1>{% block title %} {{ object.title }} {% endblock title %}</h1>
                    <p class=" text-muted">{{ object.author }} | {{ object.created_on }}</p>

                    <!-- /carrot-cake/static/placeholder_cake -->

                    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ object.image }}" alt="Card image cap">
                    <p class="card-text "><pre class="recipe">{{ object.content|safe }}</pre></p>
                </div>
                </div>

                {% block sidebar %} {% include 'sidebar.html' %} {% endblock sidebar %}
                </div>
            </div>

            {% endblock content %}
```

You've also referred to the static path with your URL examples. If you're uploading something to a field in a model you've created, that won't use your static path. That will use your media settings instead.

Static files include css/javascript/images etc, but media files are user-uploaded content.

And I've just spotted your use of the `safe` filter. You don't need a space in there when you're using filters.

Comment: so this is a user that updates the site from the admin.. that counts as using the media folder rather than the static folder?

Comment: Correct. The static folder is for images (css or JS) that you add to your project via source control. Those files that exist alongside the python code.

Comment: Please see the answer I figured out on my own.. thanks for the tips regarding the ``object``.

Answer (score 0):

This one line fixed what I was trying to do:

`<img class="card-img-top" src= "{% url 'home' %}{{ post.image }}" alt="Card image cap">`

Essentially using the same link as the one from the first view/template (index) but from the 2nd view.. (post_detail)

Comment: What does the generated `src` value look like?

Comment: ``<img class="card-img-top" src= "/static/placeholder_cake.PNG" alt="Card image cap">``

Comment: Ok so `{% url 'home' %}` isn't doing anything there because that resolves to `/`.  I'm also not sure how you're getting `post` to exist in the detail template given your view doesn't pass `post` in the context.

Comment: look at my view.. ``Post`` is in there

Comment: maybe this? 
I didn't paste the top with the imports:
``from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic
from .models import Post``

Comment: No, that's `Post`, the class of your model to tell django which model to query using the slug from your URL; `{% url 'post_detail' post.slug %}`. Your template has `post` which is not the same. That's why I talked about using `object` in the detail template. For a file field you might also do something like `{{ object.image.url }}`